# Which data type to use for storing into array of any type values

Tags: python

I would like to store and access to multiple type values through a same name via arrays (i.e. using name[i]). Consider

```
9 (an integer)
[1.,3.,5.] (list of floats)
"foo" (a string)
```

Lets say I would like to store these values into variable "stor" as follows

```
stor[1] = 9
stor[2] = [1.,3.,5.]
stor[3] = "foo"
```

However, if I run that kind of association, python shows : "name 'stor' is not defined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to declare stor:

```
stor = []
```

Then you can use `stor.append("value")` to add the value into stor.

In your case,

```
stor = []
stor.append(9)
stor.append([1.,3.,5.])
stor.append("foo")
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, `stor` is not defined. You need to create it before you can assign values. And you can't subscript beyond the end of the array.

You can create the array directly:

```
stor = [9, [1.,3.,5.], "foo"]
```

Or you could build it up:

```
stor = []
stor.append(9)
stor.append([1.0, 3.0, 5.0])
stor.append("foo")
```